# Injecting information from HttpContext into constructor with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control, httpcontext

We have some tables in a project we're working with and one of the standards that's been set is to have all tables contain some fields for auditing. I have set up in my datalayer a way to automatically record the two fields anytime a commit to the database occurs. However I need to get from the user name from the HttpContext. My datalayer is basically set up like this:

```
    public UnitOfWork(DataContext dataContext, IUserIdentity identity)
    {
        //Misc
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        EntryNm = identity.UserId;

        //Repositories
        SomeRepository = new SomeRepository(dataContext);
     }
```

Ninject bindings

```
        kernel.Bind<DataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IUserIdentity>().To<UserIdentity>();
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
```

UserIdentity

```
public interface IUserIdentity
{
    string UserId { get; }
}

public class UserIdentity : IUserIdentity
{
    public string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run the the program I always get an empty string from identity.UserId instead of the current identity. I'm very new to dependency injection but the way I'm wanting it to work is on every request the UnitOfWork is created with the context which should also pass in the UserId from the current HTTPContext.

Comment: Your method is valid. If `User.Identity.Name` returns an empty string, it probabl means you're not running in the context of a logged in user.

Comment: @Steven You're right I think. I'm pretty sure my issue is that since I have it in a seperate project (the data layer) that the HttpContext is created there in that projects memory from what little I understand about it. I might be able to get around it with something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx), but for now I'm decided to go a differnt route and just call it on Save so it can live in the web project where it works.